# Картинки для оптимизации на всех устройствах

Tags: xcode, ios, iphone

Здравствуйте.

Вопрос новичка: скажите, если мое приложение оптимизированно для всех устройств и там 50 картинок, то из-за разных размеров там их становится в 10 раз больше одних и тех же! Когда я выложу, вес будет сосчитан с учетом 500 картинок? Как тогда решается такая проблема, чтоб вес приложения оставался маленький?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько вариантов:

1) Хранить максимальный размер, при запуске изменять размер под устройство с сохранением на диск. Возможна потеря качества.

2) Подгружать картинки или другой контент во время запуска приложения и опять же сохранять на диск. Можно со своего сервера, можно с яблочного.

3) Оптимизировать все картинки, чтобы они занимали меньше места. Прогнать все изображения через оптимизаторы.

Comment: Получается, самый лучший вариант - это второй, но тут высший пилотаж программирования, если новичок, то третий оптимальный, но на много не уменьшить! А если, как вариант, выпустить для ipad и iphone два разных приложения?

Comment: @SergeyXcode Делайте так, как в данный момент удобнее. Судя по количеству отдельных версий, этот метод популярен.

Comment: спасибо за быстрый и полный ответ!

Answer (score 3):

Некоторые вещи можно рисовать в коде. Это позволяет выбросить картинки, которые могут быть нарисованы в коде, из приложения. Если их много, то, возможно, это будет даже существенно для размера.

1. Рисовать можно с помощью [UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html) или [CoreGraphics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH202-TPXREF101). Подходит, например, для линий, прямоугольников, или для рисования градиентов.
2. Пользоваться возможностями CALayer, если нужно нарисовать границу вокруг view, скруглить углы или добавить тень. [Пример.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2502/calayers-tutorial-for-ios-introduction-to-calayers-tutorial)

Comment: Совет Насти мне больше нравится, плюс к ее списку: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/

Comment: спасибо, буду пользоваться, но в моем случае там 50 фотографий.